# RESTClient not returning the Server Response Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, proxy, rest-client

I am working on a ruby project which involve using RESTClient to reach out to an API. The API returns a 400 HTTP Status Code for a particular result with an accompanying response message (A JSON Response).

But when I check the response of my call:

```
response = RESTClient.post(...) {
    logger.info response.to_s
}
```

I am getting a Proxy Server 400 page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
   <title>400 Bad Request</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Bad Request</h1>
  <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
  </p>
 </body></html>
```

which is not what I'm expecting.

Please what could be wrong?

Also, the behaviour is different with DEV and TEST Environment. On DEV Environment, it's giving the JSON while on TEST, I'm getting this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your API you can enable response in JSON format to any request. Just add this to your base API controller:

```
  before_filter :default_request_format

  private

  def default_request_format
    request.format = :json
  end
```

If this is not your API you should specify `Accept` header with JSON content type.

Comment: I already set the Accept type in my request, I set content_type to :json... It's working on DEV perfectly but not on TEST.